# MIME media type (content type) for representing a URL?

Tags: url, mime-types

I'm looking for the correct MIME media type (or content type) for documents that contain a single URL such as **http://example.com/123/abc**.

I checked IANA's [MIME type registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types), but couldn't find a suitable one for a URL or URI.

Should I create a custom MIME type for this purpose or use the closest registered that applies? It will be used by a RESTful API that returns a URL in the HTTP body for specific calls, to differentiate from others that do not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to use `text/uri-list` defined in [RFC 2483 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2483#section-5). You are only returning a single URL, but there is nothing in the spec saying it can't be a list of one. To conform to the spec, just make sure the URL is all on one line and terminated with a CRLF pair.

Answer (score 1):

`text/x-uri` should be fine, it's the most used as far as I know.

Comment: Can you quote a reference or cite evidence for that?  I'm not seeing it on the majority or MIME lists I've found from Googling...